# Parentheses precedence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parentheses

I want to know if there is a way to deal with a string with multiple operations like:

String evaluate = '((Do this) AND (Then this)) OR (Do this)

To get an array like:

```
[(Do this) AND (Next this), OR (Do this)]
```

I'm trying to use split but that gives an array like:

```
[Do this, AND, Next this, OR, Do this]
```

How can I get an array like the one I need? My logic is blocked

Comment: In general you have to write an expression grammar parser. There's no built-in facility for doing that.

Comment: You want a parser, not a regex.

Comment: Also take a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

Comment: Yes what I wanted was a parser but I was a little confused about getting all the arguments one by one, the binary expression tree works for me thank you so much for saving me